# Inserting rows into UITableView using data that's passed from another view controller via delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I've set the delegate properly so that two different view controllers communicate with each other. There's no problem in passing the data (I've checked and the data passing is successful). The only problem I'm having is when I use the following code to insert a new row:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: paymentMethodArray.count - 1, section: 0)
tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
tableView.reloadData()
```

it doesn't do anything (it doesn't update the row but data is passed and appended to the array). This code however works when I'm calling the function from the same view controller without having to come back from another view controller (data is sent from AddPaymentViewController to this view controller, AddPaymentViewController is the vc that comes after the current vc). My guess is that my code for destination segue or view controller is wrong.

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let addPaymentViewController = segue.destination as! AddPaymentViewController
    addPaymentViewController.delegate = self
}
```

If you need more information on this I can add on to it. Just let me know, thanks.

Comment: Apart from the issue **never** call `reloadData()` right after `insertRows(... /deleteRows(...`. because insert/delete updates the UI. And where do you add the corresponding item to the data source array?

Comment: I add the passed data to the array right before "let indexPath..." and so in this case where should I be putting reloadData()?

Comment: Delete the line, it's redundant and you are losing the animation.

Comment: @vadian true, do you see the problem of my code besides that? It seems like it's just the row insertion that's not happening. The row insertion worked when I called the function from the same view controller. In addition, it's 100% clear that the data is being passed properly too.

Comment: I guess the issue is not directly related to the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe double check that number of rows in the table have updated after you have added more rows.

```
func tableView(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int)
```

Also check if you would like to use `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()` around insertion of new cell to the table.

Comment: Please don't suggest `beginUpdates / endUpdates`. It's useless in this case.

Comment: So I tried what you said and it says the row has been added but it doesn't show on the screen. I'm assuming something is not working with the animation then?

Comment: I couldn't spot any error in the code that you have included in the question. Maybe also review `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` so that nothing is going wrong there. As https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614879-insertrowsatindexpaths?language=objc states delegate and data source methods are called after you insert the row to update visible cells.